# Открытие страницы mail.ru по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: email, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, код, который по нажатию на кнопку открывает mail.ru для отправки сообщения на ящик админу сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Для сайта это `<a href="mailto://адрес_админа">Написать письмо.</a>`
А вообще, в идеале было бы неплохо, если бы вы более точно описали проблему.

Comment: Вообще мне нужно чтобы на сайте была кнопка меняющая цвет при наведении, и по нажатию на нее открывается майл.ру готовый для отправки сообщения на admin@domain.ru

Comment: Но вы же не знаете, есть ли у пользователя аккаунт на mаil.ru. Приведенная ссылка либо открывает установленный почтовый клиент, либо переходит на открытую ранее страницу отправки письма через web-интерфейс. Если хотите именно кнопку, то создавайте орган управления button и вешайте на него события onClick - для перехода по щелчку мыши и onmouseover - для смены цвета